# One binding to user control works, second doesn't

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I've created user control, the code for property which I want to bind is:

```
public Color Value
{
    get
    {
        return (Color)this.GetValue(this.ValueProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(this.ValueProperty, value);
    }
}

public readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(Color), 
    typeof(ColorSlider), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Red))
```

I have two instances of this control in my page:

```
<local:ColorSlider x:Name="ColorsSlider1" />
<!--...-->
<local:ColorSlider x:Name="ColorsSlider3" />
```

And controls with values, that I want to bind to (from `ColorSlider` to `Canvas` and `TextBlock`):

```
<Canvas x:Name="TileCanvas" Grid.Column="0" Margin="30" Width="173" Height="173"
        Background="{Binding Value, ElementName=ColorsSlider1, Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidBrushConverter}}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="TileText" Text="dsdfsdfsf"
               Foreground="{Binding Value, ElementName=ColorsSlider3, Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidBrushConverter}}"/>
</Canvas>
```

So here's the problem. Binding to the `Canvas` works, but binding to the `TextBlock` doesn't! It is interesting that if I remove `ColorSlider3` a binding to the `TextBlock` will work! Also the binding will update the `TextBlock` background if I set the binding to `ColorSlider3`.

So it seems that I can bind values only from the latest instance of one `UserControl`. Why is this the case and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Dependency Property is not correctly defined... lacks the static part, and don't need the "this":

```
public Color Value
{
  get
  {
    return (Color)this.GetValue(ValueProperty);
  }

  set
  {
    this.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
  }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(Color),
  typeof(ColorSlider), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Red));
```

EDIT -----------------

Good to know it works for you. However, the real reason MS decided it to be static... never though about it, but according to MSDN:

"Custom Dependency Properties.

If you want properties on your custom types to support value expressions, property invalidation, per-type default values, inheritance, data binding, animation, or styling, you should back these CLR properties with a dependency property following these guidelines and procedures:

1. Register a dependency property using the Register method; this method returns a DependencyProperty, which you should store as an accessible **static** read-only field in your class..."

Comment: That's it! Now it works perfectly. Can you briefly explain what changes when DependencyProperty is static? Why is it working now, but when it was non-static it didn't worked?

Comment: And, by the way, Visual Studio includes the "propdp" snippet to help you write your custom Dependency Properties.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have it set to ColorsSlider2 instead of ColorsSlider3

Comment: I apologise for misleading you. It supposed to bed `ElementName=ColorSlider3`. I've just pasted code after my experiments, not the original one. But changing it to ColorSlider3 doesn't solve the problem.